# XCode, how to preserve directory hierarchy

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, macos, xcode4.2

I need to port some Java classes to Objective-C, the final product: a Framework (for Mac Apps) and a static library (for iOS).

The original Java code is organized in the standard Java's way:
com.company.project...

so, for example, I have Util.java in 3 places

> com.company.project.xxx
>   com.company.project.yyy
>   com.company.project.xxx.zzz

1. How can I achieve Xcode to preserve the directory structure of my
   header files?, I see it just put all my .h files in the same place. But, I have seen something like

   > import "FoundationKit/Something.h"
2. Is this directory hierarchy 'natural' for iOS/Mac code?, if not, what do you suggest?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That #import tag you have shown does not list a directory structure (well, it kind of does, but it's not meant to be).  What it means is that inside FoundationKit there is a header called Something.h.  Instead of #importing the framework itself (which doesn't work anyways), we tell the compiler to include specific header files (because frameworks sometimes include a convenient header file that imports all of the private headers, which saves us a lot of trouble).

What you might want to do with your framework target is drag every .h into the private section except for your 'convenient' header which will be public.  That way, your framework can just be dragged into your project and accessed with `#import <Framework/FrmwkCollection.h>`